# Laravel Queue Through the Too many attempt Error After first queue process done

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, supervisord, laravel-queue

I am running a queue using a supervisor in laravel. my supervisor configuration is here.

```
[program:dev]
command=php artisan queue:work --tries=1 --env=local --timeout=12000
directory=/var/www/html/dev/dev
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/dev/dev/storage/logs/myqueue_supervisord.log
redirect_stderr=true
numprocs=2
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

Now, I run the two queues at a time. The First Is working perfectly. But the second one this through the following error in the middle (after the first queue process is done).

```
[2019-11-15 12:07:18] local.ERROR: App\Jobs\ProductImport has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Queue\\MaxAttemptsExceededException(code: 0): App\\Jobs\\ProductImport has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out. at /var/www/html/dev/devflexi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php:401)
```

Comment: please post the second job script

Comment: I think the job is taking too long to finish so either increase the timeout or check out the code for errors, don't forget to call php artisan queue:retry all.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia first and the second queue run the same script. I mentioned the 2 processes here.

Comment: @AnasBakro here is the problem is once the first process completes, it tries to run the second one, at that time the --tries=1 failed that why it moves into the failed evet.